# Meteor Single collection Field Editable Content

Tags: javascript, meteor, insert-update

I am attempting to make a element in a meteor template editable via a update function. The data changes when it is inserted from a server side code in the `fixture.js` code. However I have no luck updating it via a editable form with some `Template.name.events({});` code and, creating a collection, publishing and subscribing to it. The very last piece of code is the `fixture.js` file. So in some regard I can insert into the collection and update it, but I have no luck with the edit `financialsEdit` template. The `router.js` file I included only contains parts regarding the `financials` template. If needed I will post more.

Basically I can't update a collection value with a update function using `$set` and passing a key value pair.

**UPDATE**: I added the permissions.js file in the lib directory to show what `ownsDocument` returns.

Here is my code.

client Directory

`client/editable/edit_financial.js`

```
Template.financialsEdit.events({
  'submit .financialsEdit': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var currentFinanceId = this._id;

    var financialsProperties = {
      issuedOutstanding: $('#issuedOutstanding').val()
    }

    Financials.update(currentFinanceId, {$set: financialsProperties}, function(error) {
      if (error) {
        alert(error.reason);
      } else {
        console.log(financialsProperties);
        // Router.go('financials');
        Router.go('financials');
      }
    });

  }

});
```

`client/editable/financials_helpers.js`

```
Template.financials.helpers({
  financials: function() {
    return Financials.find();
  },
  ownFinancial: function() {
    return this.userId === Meteor.userId();
  }
});
```

`client/editable/financials`

```
<template name="financials">
  <div id="finance">
  {{#each financials}}
   <h2>Issued Outstand : {{issuedOutstanding}}</h2>
  {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>
```

`client/editable/financials_edit.html`

```
<template name="financialsEdit">
  <form class="main form financialsEdit">
    <input id="issuedOutstanding" type="number" value="{{issuedOutstanding}}" placeholder="{{issuedOutstanding}}" class="form-control">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit"/>
  </form>
</template>
```

lib Directory
`lib/router.js`

```
Router.route('/financials', function () {
  this.render('financials');
});
Router.route('/financialsedit', {name: 'financialsEdit'});
```

`lib/collections/financials.js`

```
Financials = new Mongo.Collection('financials');

Financials.allow({
  update: function(userId, financial) { return ownsDocument(userId, financial); },
  remove: function(userId, financial) { return ownsDocument(userId, financial); },
});

Financials.deny({
  update: function(userId, financial, fieldNames) {
    // may only edit the following two fields:
    return (_.without(fieldNames, 'issuedOutstanding').length > 0);
  }
});
```

`lib/permissions.js`

```
// check that the userId specified owns the documents
ownsDocument = function(userId, doc) {
  return doc && doc.userId === userId;
}
```

`server/publications.js`

```
Meteor.publish('financials', function() {
  return Financials.find();
});
```

`server/fixture.js`

```
if (Financials.find().count() === 0) {
  Financials.insert({
    issuedOutstanding: '43253242'
  });
}
```

Comment: Do you get any console output? And what happens if you try to insert a document in the console, i.e. Financials.insert();?

Comment: @SandervandenAkker There is no errors in the console, however running a insert on the client side adds a new field, and then removes it with the error `No allow validators set on restricted collection for method 'insert'` however I am trying to update not insert, because insert creates a new field, and I want to change a existing one.

Comment: Of course, sorry. So running Financials.update from the console does work?

Comment: And are you sure your ownsDocument function returns true?

Comment: @SandervandenAkker I am pretty sure it has to do with the fact the collection Financials has no userId field. I am having trouble figuring out how to insert the meteor user id, so then it can be updated.

Comment: @SandervandenAkker I have added my permissions.js folder which shows what `ownsDocument` returns.